# WiX Bootstrap - The element contains an unhandled extension attribute

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, wix4

I am having trouble developing a WiX Bootstrap Application using WiX Toolset 4.0.

My main objective right now is to check and prevent from reinstalling .NET 4.5 Framework when running the installer. So I need to use the RegistrySearch extension attribute from the xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" namespace but I am getting the following error.

> The Fragment element contains an unhandled extension attribute
>   'RegistrySearch'. Please ensure that the extension for attributes in
>   the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension' namespace has
>   been provided.

I already added the reference to WixUtilExtension.dll and I also get this error when trying to add PrereqPackage from the BalExtension namespace.

> The ExePackage element contains an unhandled extension attribute
>   'PrereqPackage'. Please ensure that the extension for attributes in
>   the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension' namespace has
>   been provided.

Here is my Bundle.wxs file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle Name="Camille" 
          Version="1.0.0.0" 
          Manufacturer="Dummy" 
          UpgradeCode="A48D5F63-0E35-4521-A659-36726E31D080" 
          Compressed="yes"
          DisableModify="button"
          >
    <!--TODO: Add IconSourceFile argument-->
     <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">       
      <Payload SourceFile="..\DummyInstaller.BootstrapperApplication\BootstrapperCore.config"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\DummyInstaller.BootstrapperApplication\bin\Release\DummyInstaller.BootstrapperApplication.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\Libs\Dummy.UI.Tools.WPF.MVVMFramework.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\Libs\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"/>     
     </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
 

  <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx45'/>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\MSI\DummyInstaller.msi" Id="DummyPackageId" Cache="yes" Visible="no" Vital="yes"/>
  </Chain>    
 </Bundle>
  
  <Fragment>
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion" Win64="yes" />
        
    <!-- .NET 4.5 only installed if Vista or higher AND it's not already installed-->
    <PackageGroup Id="Netfx45">
      <ExePackage Id="Netfx45" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" InstallCommand="/q"
                  bal:PrereqPackage="yes"
                  SourceFile="dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe"
                  DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/a/4/ba4a7e71-2906-4b2d-a0e1-80cf16844f5f/dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe"
                  DetectCondition="(Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;))"
                  InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0) AND (NOT (Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot; OR Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;))"/>
    </PackageGroup>  
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? I've tried building this in Visual Studios and by command line, and same error both times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the wrong iis link. Please check this [Migration](http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/4561-migrate-v3-source-code-to-v4/) page.

Fix: Rename `http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension` to `http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal`

Fix: Rename `http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension` to `http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util`